# Ordering a Rails DataTable column by another value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, datatable

I am building a helpdesk application.  I have a model called TicketDetail, with a table which uses datatables to get its data via JSON.  This is in order to periodically recalculate the time a ticket has been open.  The time taken is formatted by a simple helper so it's in the format "dd:hh:mm", but it should be sorted by the time (stored as a decimal) multiplied by a weighting.  Here's the datatables definition

```
var table = $('#ticket_details').DataTable({
 order: [[ 8, "desc" ], [ 9, "desc" ], [ 2, "asc" ]],
 stateSave: true,
 deferRender: true,
 ajax: $('#ticket_details').data('source'),
 "columns": [
 { "data": "reference_number" },
 { "data": "location" },
 { "data": "title" },
 { "data": "parent", className: "hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" },
 { "data": { _:"time_display.time", sort: "time_display.decimal_time"}},
 { "data": "created_by", className: "hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" }
 ]
 } ); 

setInterval( function () {
table.ajax.reload( null, false ); }, 60000 );
```

Here's a simplified sample record, where the ticket has been open 3 days and 6 hours, with a weighting of x2 (i.e. 3.25 * 2 = 6.5:

```
{
 data: [
  {
   id: 140,
   parent: null,
   title: "[",
   location: "<a href="/en-GB/stores/123">Bond St</a>",
   ticket_sla: "16 Hours",
   reference_number: "<a href="/en-GB/ticket_details/140/edit">1606210001</a>",
   ticket_sla_weighting: 2,
   time_display: {
   time: "<span class = "label label-danger">03:06:00</span>",
   decimal_time: 6.5
   }
 ]
}
```

The problem is that the datatable sorts correctly if I display the decimal_time, but as soon as I put the formatted time in the  class, it sorts simply by the number of days, immediately to the left of the colon. (So 03:06:00 and 03:18:00 would not get sorted properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Date/Time sorting in DataTable You need to use it's Sorting plug-ins

For Example,
You need to include this js files :

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js
```

and then, In your jQuery use this as

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'HH:mm MMM D, YY' ); // Pass your date time format as param
```

For Deeper reference please check :

[Sorting Plugins](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

[Ultimate date / time sorting plugin](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out, but. I don't want to sort by a Date Time.  I want a formatted html tag, sorted by a float.  Eg. "03:06:00" sorted by 6.5.

Comment: Yes, You also can do that, Please check the reference link

Comment: In this case, You need to add one more column to your dataTable and then perform sort on that and hide that column

Comment: // Sort column 1 by column 2
'columnDefs': [
    { 'orderData':[2], 'targets': [1] },
    {
        'targets': [2],
        'visible': false,
        'searchable': false
    },
],

Comment: OK.  I've finally got this to work based on your answer. I cannot get hiding to work, but this does it.  `{ "data": "time", "orderData": 9 },
        { "data": "decimal_time", "searchable": false, className: "hidden"},`.  If you update your answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: `'searchable': false` will hide the column you should need to replace `className: "hidden"` with `'searchable': false`

Comment: the problem here was `"visible": false` did not hide it, hence the css class.  Are you suggesting it's to do with double not single quotes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115988/discussion-between-hardik-kanjariya-and-thenapking).